# Adding collection of owned objects

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2, owned-types

I've got a domain model with collection of owned types. When I try to add more than one object in the ownedtyped collection? I get an exception:

> **System.InvalidOperationException**: 'The instance of entity type 'ChildItem' cannot be tracked because another 
>   instance with the key value '{NameId: -2147482647, Id: 0}' is already being 
>   tracked. When replacing owned entities modify the properties without changing 
>   the instance or detach the previous owned entity entry first.'

How can it be solved?

**UPDATED**

**My domain classes:**

```
public class Parent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Child Name { get; set; }
        public Child ShortName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public List<ChildItem> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
    }
```

**My DbContext:**

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
                .OwnsOne(c => c.Name, d =>
                {
                    d.OwnsMany(c => c.Items, a =>
                    {
                        a.HasForeignKey("NameId");
                        a.Property<int>("Id");
                        a.HasKey("NameId", "Id");
                        a.ToTable("ParentNameItems");
                    })
                    .ToTable("ParentName");
                })
                .ToTable("Parent");

                modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
                .OwnsOne(c => c.ShortName, d =>
                {
                    d.OwnsMany(c => c.Items, a =>
                    {
                        a.HasForeignKey("NameId");
                        a.Property<int>("Id");
                        a.HasKey("NameId", "Id");
                        a.ToTable("ParentShortNameItems");
                    })
                    .ToTable("ParentShortName");
                })
                .ToTable("Parent");
        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new ApplicationContext();

            var parent = new Parent()
            {
                Name = new Child()
                {
                    Items = new List<ChildItem>()
                    {
                        new ChildItem() { Text = "First value", Language = "en-en"},
                        new ChildItem() { Text = "Second value", Language = "en-en"}
                    }
                },
                ShortName = new Child()
                {
                    Items = new List<ChildItem>()
                    {
                        new ChildItem() { Text = "First short value", Language = "en-en"},
                        new ChildItem() { Text = "Second short value", Language = "en-en"}
                    }
                }
            };

            context.Set<Parent>().Add(parent);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all you classes don't make sense. If anything it should be

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

a parent should have many children (or none possibly, empty list maybe?). What about the child's name and id, doesn't he have one of each ? also maybe a ParentId maybe something like

```
public class Child
{
    public virtual List<ChildItem> Items { get; set; } //why virtual? you planning to inherit?
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public int ParentId {get; set; }
}
```

That looks a little better, I should think. The database should have matching tables. and let's be honest EF (Entity Framework) **auto create** will do 99% of the work for you, so please use it.

Comment: Thanx for a quick answer! To be closer to my real situation, I've made some updates in code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. It was in line

```
a.HasKey("NameId", "Id");
```

in `OnModelCreating` method.
I used an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types) where was written abount configuring Collections of owned types.

After deleting "NameId" field from Key definition

```
a.HasKey("Id");
```

everything works fine now.